# Is there a name for this sequence that involves adding seq[n] repetitions where n is the next natural number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence starts as: `seq = [0, 1, 2, 2]` and then the next natural number is 3, so 3 is added `seq[3]` times.

Eventually we will end up with `0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21` and so on.

I looked at OEIS but could not find such a sequence.

Comment: Where does it pop up?

Comment: It is [OEIS sequence A001462](https://oeis.org/A001462) "Golomb's sequence:  a(n) is the number of times n occurs, starting with a(1) = 1".